# Seeking Android app to be GPS Logger and POI recorder, with offline map?

Tags: shapefile, software-recommendations, point-of-interest, tracking, value-list

I am looking for a good app that can do one or many of my below listed requirements. They are listed with the most fundamental functions first. Preferably the app can do all of it, but it should at least pass the first requirements.

- Have track logger and capability of making own POI
- Use offline maps to display position/track/POI using OSM or something else
- For the twist: I want to use the app for outdoor surveying of habitat/wildlife. Where a POI  is recorded I want to be able to select habitat/species from a list of predefined values, so I dont need to type in the value myself. Later I want to export that information into a shapefile and build up a database with observations.

I have not been looking into it too much, but I think ArcMap collector could do this? But I am looking for a free app to easy distribute it to volunteers etc.

Any ideas for this?

Answer (score 3):

[Open Data Kit](http://opendatakit.org/) combined with ODK Collect is perfect for the field survey portion of your question.  It is free and open-source software.  [ODK Aggregate](http://opendatakit.org/use/aggregate/) is the server component where your data will be stored. [ODK Collect](http://opendatakit.org/use/collect/) is the app you'll install on the Android phone of each volunteer.
[This video](http://youtu.be/HqqUdfz9Uyc) is a great overview of the Open Data Kit suite of tools.
Go to [build.opendatakit.org](http://build.opendatakit.org/) and begin making a form to see all of the data types that may be collected.

I've used [OsmAnd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand) just a bit for offline OSM map access.

Answer (score -1):

I think the app called 
Oruxmaps is right for you